# Entity Reference Field when logged out

Tags: views, 8, entities

I have an **Entity Reference Field** attached to a **Content Type**. 
This field references **Views**, and has a field format of **Entity ID**

When I am **logged in**, the field appears fine, however it does not appear when I am **logged out**, it does not even display template tags when debug is turned on, so it seems it is getting skipped all together.

Other **Entity Reference** fields appear fine when logged out (taxonomy, webform etc), and if I use the `views_embed_view` function, it appears fine.

There are also no field level permissions set.

This did used to work, but somewhere along the line there must have been an update that causes this issue.

Im on **8.5.6** and the latest version of the entity module.

Thanks.

Comment: So you use the Entity module. Seems to be more for experimental stuff not yet ready for core. Why you use this module? And what is a display type "Entity ID" ?

Comment: I inherited the site a little while ago and its had some third party changes (external contractors) since, so thats how its setup. And by the display type, I should have said **format**, when you are changing field display formats on this page: `/admin/structure/types/manage/{content_type}/display/full`

Comment: You mean the field formatter. If you want to see a View you need "Views reference".

Comment: Because of the way things have been set up, I *have* to use **Entity ID**, the view shows fine when I'm logged in, and used to work when logged out, but since the beginning of the year(ish) I can no longer see it for logged out users, the point isn't really about the view not showing, but the entity reference field not being rendered at all.

Comment: Is what the field renders accessible to anonymous users? This sounds like it might be a node access issue.

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure how I would check that, the view I'm referencing is viewable to anonymous users, but how would I test if the entity reference field its self is?

Comment: OK, now after you've clarified this we know for sure the View is not produced by the field formatter. So there needs to be code added somewhere which replaces the field containing only the entity id with a field containing the View. If this code fails to load the View for some reason it might replace the field with NULL. But without knowing the code this is impossible to tell.

Comment: So it tunrs out after sticking some dumps into core, the **Entity ID** field formatter referencing the view, needs the **administer views** permission to display.

Comment: Instead of granting this permission to anonymous users I would use the field formatter from https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference

Comment: Yeah I did see that module in my travels, thanks for confirming I should use it!